# Como subir una imagen a base de datos desde vue a laravel mediante axios?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, imagen, axios, store

Estoy haciendo un crud donde tengo guardar ubicación de una imagen con axios

**Este es mi formulario**

```
       <label for="book">Imagen:</label>
<input type="file" @change="obtenerImage"class="formcontrol" id="book">
```

**Este son mis métodos **

```
      obtenerImage(e){
              this.image=e.target.files[0];
              
        },
             addBook(){
                const fd= new FormData();
                const re=fd.append('image',this.image);
                let url="libros/guardar";
                axios.post(url,{
                    'name':this.name,
                     'image':re
                       
                }).then(function(response){
                  this.getLibros(),
                  this.limpiarCampos()                     
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });


            },
```

Este es mi controlador

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
         if ($request->hasFile('image')){
        $request->file('image')->store('images');
         }
    $libros=$this->book->create($request->all());
    return response()->json($libros);

}
```

**Esta es mi ruta**

```
Route::post('libros/guardar','BookController@store');
```

**Este es la migracion del campo imagen**

```
$table->string('image')->after('name')->nullable();
```

El log de laravel me marcaba el error de que no permitía el campo de imagen vacio asi que lo puse nullable pero ahora no se guarda el archivo

Comment: ¿Qué te dice el error de Laravel?

Comment: ya lo añadi ...

Comment: En laravel, típicamente, los archivos subidos se guardan en el disco; y en la base de datos guardas la ubicación. Estás seguro de que quieres guardar el archivo en BD? Que tipo de dato es la columna image de la tabla?

Comment: si asi es ,quiero guardar la ubicacion de la imagen y el tipo de dato es un string

Comment: Así como lo tienes estás tratando de guardar el archivo dentro de la base de datos. Debes evaluar el archivo, es decir, si te llega algo con hasFile y luego usar store para guardarl y crear una ruta para almacenarlo.

Comment: si ya lo hice gaidyjg pero no se guarda la imagen ;c